# The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FileUpload.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.FileUpload" %>
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>


<div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager id="scriptManager1" runat="server" />

        <div>
            <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" id="fileUpload1" onclientuploadcomplete="uploadComplete" onclientuploaderror="uploadError"
                completebackcolor="White" width="350px" uploaderstyle="Modern" uploadingbackcolor="#CCFFFF"
                throbberid="imgLoad" onuploadedcomplete="fileUploadComplete"></ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="imgLoad" runat="server" ImageUrl="loading.gif" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I have installed `AjaxControlToolKit`, added a reference to it, added these controls to Toolbox. `ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload` is recognisable. But, I am getting `"The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"` for `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager`.

How to resolve it?

Comment: did you try to add this from toolbox? if possible also include sections of your config file. tags conflicted sometimes

Answer (score 0):

you add ScriptManager AS

```
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <ajaxtoolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="fileUpload1" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete"
                OnClientUploadError="uploadError" CompleteBackColor="White" Width="350px" UploaderStyle="Modern"
                UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF" ThrobberID="imgLoad" OnUploadedComplete="fileUploadComplete">
            </ajaxtoolkit:AsyncFileUpload>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="imgLoad" runat="server" ImageUrl="loading.gif" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
```